# Morse code w/ text files and comparing indexes

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files, morse-code

Everyone. I am having trouble with my morse code.  I am trying to convert a English message or text like "A" into morse code ".-"

However, I am having trouble with my convert method. When, I run my code I get the message back which find but, I get my whole entire morse code that I read in as well.

My teacher told me I need to compare the the indexes so, I can print the value of the morse code. But, I am still hung up on the logic.

Here is what I got so far:

```
public class MorseCode {

    public static ArrayList<String> alpha;
    public static ArrayList<String> codes;

    /**
    * This Constructor actually imports the list of Morse Code Characters and adds it to an ArrayList.
    */
    public MorseCode() throws IOException
    {
        String token = "";
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("morsecode.txt"));

        codes = new ArrayList<String>();
        codes.add(".-");
        codes.add("-...");
        codes.add("-.-.");

        while(inFile.hasNext())
        {
            token = inFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(token);
        }
        inFile.close();
    }

    public static void alpha () throws IOException
    {
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("alphabet.txt"));
        String cake = "";

        alpha = new ArrayList<String>();
        alpha.add("A");
        alpha.add("B");
        alpha.add("C");

        while(inFile.hasNext())
        {
            cake = inFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(cake);
        }
        inFile.close();
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getMorse()//ArrayList<String> codes
    {
        ArrayList codes = new ArrayList<String>();
        return codes;                
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getAlpha()//ArrayList<String> alpha
    {
        ArrayList alpha = new ArrayList<String>();
        return alpha;
    }

    public static void  Morse ( String token)
    {
        for( String m : codes)
        {
            token = m;
            System.out.println(m);
        }
    }

    public static void Alpha(String cake)
    {
        for( String a : alpha)
        {
            cake = a;

            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }

    public static String convertCode (String myMessage)
    {
        alpha = new ArrayList<String>();
        String myLetter = "";
        String cake = "";
        int myindex = 0;
        for(int index = 0; index < myMessage.length(); index++)
        {
            myLetter = myMessage.substring(index,index + 1);

            for( int in = 0; in < alpha.size(); in++)
            {
                if(alpha.get(in).equals(myLetter))
                {
                    index = in;
                }
                cake += codes.get(in);
                System.out.println(cake);   
            }
        }

        return cake;
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like your answer needs to be more precise. This is a pretty vague question, in fact, the grammar in it is kind of quirky. What kind of troubleshooting have you done to find the source of the issue?

Comment: Why do you reset the value of `alpha` and `code` (`alpha = new ArrayList<String>();`) that often? Your `convertCode` function won't work, since you removed the values from `alpha` by re-initializing it.

Answer (score 1):

What Doctuer said is true, you seem to be resetting the values too often.

This convert function should work though, it will return a String (Encoded in Morse code) given a normal English word.

```
    public static String encodeMessage(String message) {

        String encodedMessage = "";

        // Loop through the String
        for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {

            // Get each Character in String format
            String character = String.valueOf(message.charAt(i));

            // Look for the index of the Character in the Alphabet List
            for(int j = 0; j < alphabet.size(); j++) {

                // If we find a match use the Index to get the corresponding Morse Value
                if(alphabet.get(j).equals(character)) {

                    encodedMessage += code.get(j);

                    // Move onto the next Letter
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Returns only the Encoded Message
        return encodedMessage;
    }
}
```